# Disabling Text Editing in an EDITTEXT box in C++ while keeping scrolling enabled

Tags: c++, winapi

So my dilemma comes from making a UI in C++ with the windows API. I need to have an EDITTEXT box which allows for scrolling but doesn't allow the user to edit the text that gets displayed in the box. So far, it looks like this.

```
EDITTEXT        ID_STATUS,7,237,439,50, WS_VSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE
```

This allows for the text to be scrolled if it's long and breaks it into new lines. However, if i add the DISABLED option to this, it disables both the scrollbar and the text. What would be the best way to solve this situation? I've also tried adding

```
SendDlgItemMessage(ID_STATUS, EM_SETREADONLY, 0, 0);
```

before the UI gets previewed to see if this would disable text editing but it doesn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is also a `readonly` property, which is distinct from `disabled`. Note that it leaves the component looking "live". I found that out by googling. Give it a try sometime! `windows disable scrollable text box`

Comment: `readonly` most definitely disables editing. What do you mean by it doesn't?

Comment: @acraig5075 i added it to a place where the UI gets rendered. Once the UI is rendered, i'm still able to edit the text that's inside EDITTEXT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`EM_SETREADONLY` is correct but you failed to actually ask it to be read-only. Try

```
SendDlgItemMessage(ID_STATUS, EM_SETREADONLY, TRUE, 0);
```

> wParam
>
> Specifies whether to set or remove the ES_READONLY style. A value of TRUE sets the ES_READONLY style; a value of FALSE removes the ES_READONLY style.

You can also specify the `ES_READONLY` style when you create the control.

Comment: So i could do EDITTEXT        ID_STATUS,7,237,439,50, WS_VSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE | ES_READONLY=TRUE?

Comment: no, `ES_READONLY` is a style, just setting the style means true.

Comment: It works, however if I click on it, the cursor thing to write text still shows up.  Any idea how to get rid of this?

Comment: @simon the user can still copy text even if it is read only. Disable the window to prevent this.